# Xpages design elements, managed bean limits

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Sorry not a coding question, not sure if I should be posting it here.

I struggle with the concept of what is 'large' in Notes nsf application design elements as opposed to the amount of data or records stored. For example it is stated that we shouldn't have too many views, but 'too many' does not give any scale whatsoever, is it 10,50,100,500 before it 'slows down'. I realise it also based on the view design but some idea of 'too many' would be beneficial. In this instance data and design elements are in the same nsf.

Is there a recommendation regarding number of elements such as XPages, Custom Controls, Managed Beans, Java Classes etc. What would be deemed excessive? In this instance I have data and logic in separate nsfs.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The problem with views count is not in the number of design elements, the problem is in indexes they generate. Index updating is expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks Frantisek, but 30 years in are there, no metrics, documentation, examples or emperical data of what is 'large' and what isn't to your knowledge?

Comment: You can have hundred's of views but is there a better way of handling the design from a maintainability point of view.  Why do you do need hundreds of views?  You can use filtering and other techniques to reduce the need for so many.  The savings is mainly size and a bit of the developer's time and sanity. As far as design elements, I haven't heard of any other than having a large amount of design elements on one page in any development environment will increase the design time, possibility of bugs and make maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have around 100 views, the application has evolved over many years and covers many aspects of the business, due to the way it is structured maintainability is fine. I guess my real question was to ensure there isn't a limit to adding managed beans, java classes, custom controls etc to my business logic application which is pulling data from several databases, into one large 'wiki' type application.

Comment: No, 30 years in there are no metrics.  How could there be? It's going depend on your hardware capabilities - and there have been pretty significant changes in that over the 30 years!  And it also depends on the rest of the load on the server, which varies a lot, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of design elements. But unless you're importing a whole JavaScript framework into an NSF, uou're not likely to hit it.

As has been mentioned, view performance is dependent on many factors. 500 decently designed views are fine. 50 badly performing views can be bad. Lots of resorts on columns impacts the number of indexes that need to be created and managed. Using `@Today` or `@Now` in a view selection formula or column formula will be a big problem. Having lots of documents that rarely change, smaller numbers of documents that are updated every 30 seconds, lots of users regularly updating - these will all be impacts on performance.

Performance in code will also impact and XPages Toolbox or agent profiling will give an idea. `DocumentCollection.count()` is slow, but sometimes is needed. NoteCollections may be quicker. There are various blog posts covering this.

A managed bean that has a Map that grows and grows will impact Java memory.

But there are always performance enhancements being made on the server side. gRPC in Domino 10 will be extremely performant. So always try to be on a recent version and keep up to date with sessions at conferences etc so you know what TCO improvements are being made.

The bottom line is without an intimate understanding of your architecture and code, no one will be able to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: In a nutshell then it is not really the amount of elements more what is contained within them or how they are designed. I do always update to the most recent version, wish I had never seen FP10 though, - but that is another story. Many thanks for your response as informative as ever.